# Swift MVVM, a ViewController without a ViewModel reference?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reference, viewcontroller

I've been wondering if it was possible to have a MVVM architecture with no reference of the ViewModel in the ViewController, I understand that it needs this reference because ViewModel works as a DataContext but I'm trying to figure it out, I want to isolate as much as possible responsibilities and dependency injection between Views and ViewModel. Have you any idea on how it is possible to achieve that in a MVVM pattern in Swift?

Comment: He is little confused about the MVVM design pattern and needs help. IMO no need to close this question in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, The question is clear, and there's a clear and short answer to it. Those guys, who closed the question should reflect if they closed it because they do not know the answer. ;)

Comment: I try to give a short answer: ViewModel and View communicate through a "binding". In SwiftUI or UIKit the binding may consist of a "view state" value and a set of action callbacks. The view takes the view state and renders it and user actions will be notified to the view model through the action callbacks.  In order to setup the binding, the View (or ViewController) needs a reference to the view model. The ViewModel may also be "type erased" hiding any details and only exposing the "Actions" and "ViewState". Usually the view _observes_ the viewState and renders itself "onChange".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let`s have a look your ideas step by step in MVVM aspects

> "No reference of ViewModel in the ViewController or View."

It is not a good idea. By referencing to viewmodel in your view you notify viewmodel. That does not mean you need to do logic in your view or viewcontroller.

> "I want to isolate as much as possible responsibilities and dependency injection between Views and ViewModel."

Exactly! ViewModel handle the all logic. View needs to be lightweight and no logic. There are many approaches in terms of binding your view to viewmodel and separating concerns. I can give an example below.

---

Move your datasource from view to viewmodel. For example if you working a tableviewdatasource then make a generic datasource( you can find many examples by google ) for your tableViewDataSource. Your viewcontroller will be something like below:

```
private var dataSource : YourTableViewDataSource<YourData>!
private var yourViewModel: YourViewModel!

self.yourTableViewDataSource = dataSource
func updateDataSource() { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, okay I see, so do you have to also initialize the ViewModel in the view then ?

Comment: you need to bind viewmodel to view. Please check it out this first of all tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HKi96v4X2A&t=720s

Comment: Thanks can you instatiante the ViewModel somewhere else than in the ViewController for injection dependency ?

Comment: @Willy Kim You can inject viewModel to controller in 3 ways. 1)  If you are doing everything programatically you can create custom initialiser and do dependency injection, else you can create a mutable stored property in controller and inject dependency  by assigning to property from outside controller. Another way is method injection, that completely depends upon scenario.